# Continuum set and connected graph

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

For topological spaces $X$, a set $A\subset X$ is continuum if $A$ is both compact and connected. Notice that if $Y\subset X$ be an open subspace of $X$ and $B\subset Y $ is continuum then $B$ is continuum in $X.$ There is well know is says : For a function $g\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, a graph of $g$ is connected iff  whenever $D$ is continuum in $R^2$ which contains points above and below the graph of $g$, then D must meet the graph of $g.$

Now, Let $f\colon \Bbb (1,2)\to \Bbb R$ be a function  that has a disconnected graph. By using that fast above there exists a continuum $D\subset (1,2)\times \Bbb R^2$ that has pints above and below the graph such that $$D\cap Gr  f=\emptyset,$$ where $Gr f$ denotes to the graph of $f.$  Since $(1,2)\times \Bbb R$  is an open set in $\Bbb R^2$, then $D$ is continuum in $R^2.$ Define a function $h\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ as follows
$$ h(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) , \ \ \ x\in(1,2) \\
      0  ,  \ \ \ \ \ \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then $h$ still has disconnected graph. Since $D$ is continuum of $\Bbb R^2$ and has point below and above  the graph and $D\cap Gr h=\emptyset.$  Does that correct? if not how I can show that $h$ has disconnected graph. Is there any easy way to show $h$ has disconnected graph.  Any help will appreciated greatly.

Comment: In the first sentence, do you mean "if $A$ is" instead of "if $X$ is"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I fixed , Do you think that works ?

Comment: It's not quite clear how you are applying the statement about a function $g$ with $\mathrm{dom}(g) = \Bbb{R}$ to the function $f$ with $\mathrm{dom}(f) = (1, 2)$, but apart from that your extension to $h$ seems OK. I think it might be easier to start from the definition of connectedness: if you have a pair of sets $A$ and $B$ that disconnect $\mathrm{Gr}(f)$, how can you extend them to a pair of sets that disconnect $\mathrm{Gr}(h)$?

Comment: @RobArthan, since the graph of $f$ iis disconnected so by using the fact there is such continuum. which is continuum in $\Bbb R^2$ since $(1,2)\times \Bbb R$ is open. I tried to use the fact there is such pair as you mentioned but I do not how I can extended them to disconnected the graph of $h$

Comment: Yes, but your $f$ does not satisfy the conditions on $g$ in the fact that you are trying to use.  I'll write up an aswer.

Comment: Rob Arthan, back to my solution,  why you said $f$ does not require the domain will be the whole real number

Comment: @NoahSchweber, do you have something to add?

Comment: @00GB: Do you have a proof for your "well known" characterization of the connectedness of the graph of $g$? I was not able to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f: (1, 2) \to \Bbb{R}$ has a disconnected graph. Then the graph $\mathrm{Gr}(f)$ is contained in the union of two disjoint non-empty closed sets, $A$ and $B$ say, such that $A \cap \mathrm{Gr}(f) \neq \emptyset$, $B \cap \mathrm{Gr}(f) \neq \emptyset$ and $A \cap B \cap \mathrm{Gr}(f) = \emptyset$. We may assume that $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of $[1, 2] \times \Bbb{R}$, (since if not, we may replace $A$ and $B$ by $A \cap ([1, 2] \times \Bbb{R})$ and $B \cap ([1, 2] \times \Bbb{R})$, respectively).

If we extend $f$ to a function $h : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, by setting $h(x) = 0$ for $x \not\in (1, 2)$, then $\mathrm{Gr}(h) = I \cup \mathrm{Gr}(f) \cup J$, where $I = (-\infty, 1] \times \{0\}$ and $J =[2, \infty) \times \{0\}$. But then, by considering the various cases as to whether $(1, 0) \in A$, $(2, 0) \in A$, $(1, 0) \in B$ and $(2, 0) \in B$, we can find non-empty closed sets $A'$ and $B'$ such that $A' \cap \mathrm{Gr}(h) \neq \emptyset$, $B' \cap \mathrm{Gr}(h) \neq \emptyset$ and $A' \cap B' \cap \mathrm{Gr}(h) = \emptyset$. E.g., if $(1, 0) \in A$ and $(2, 0) \in B$, we take $A' = I \cup A$ and $B' = B \cup J$, while if $(1,0)$ and $(2, 0)$ are both in $A$ we take $A' = I \cup A \cup J$ and $B'= B$.

Comment: Rob Arthan, someting it is not quit clear your $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $(1,2)\times \Bbb R$ since $A\cup B=\text{Gr} f\subset (1,2)\times \Bbb R$

Comment: $\mathrm{Gr}(f)$ is contained in $A \cup $B, it is not necessarily equal to $A \cup B$.

Comment: Rob Arthan , The definition that I know it must be equal.  Also, how about if these points $(1,0). (2,0),$ do not belong to $A$ and $B$

Comment: That's right, but you have to work in the relative topology on $\mathrm{Gr}(f)$: $\mathrm{Gr}(f)$ is disconnected in the relative topology iff the sets $A$ and $B$ as I describe exist. $A \cap \mathrm{Gr}(f)$ and $B \cap \mathrm{Gr}(f)$ are then your two closed sets in the relative topology whose union is precisely $\mathrm{Gr}(f)$,

Comment: Rob Arthan, I missed read your first sentence. Basically, $A$ and $B$ are closed set in $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: That's right. I made a few mistakes in the original answer, but I hope I have fixed them now.

Comment: Rob Arthan, How the case none of these points , $(1,0),(2,0)$ belong to $A$ and $B$

Comment: Then you can make an arbitrary choice. E.g. $I \cup A \cup J$ and $B$ will do.

Comment: Rob Arthan. Your solution looks okay to me.